# How to grep for tabs without using literal tabs and why does \t not work?

Tags: bash, grep, regex, posix-compliant

When I search for tabs in a file with (e)grep I use the litteral tab (`^v + <tab>`). I can not utilize `\t` as a replacement for tabs in regular expressions. With e.g. sed this expression works very well.

So is there any possibility to use a non-litteral replacement for `<tab>` and what are the backgrounds for a non working / not interpreted `\t` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825552/grep-a-tab-in-unix

Answer (score 264, accepted):

grep is using regular expressions as defined by [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX). For whatever reasons POSIX have not defined `\t` as tab.

You have several alternatives:

- tell grep to use the regular expressions as defined by perl (perl has `\t` as tab):

  ```
  grep -P "\t" foo.txt
  ```

  the man page warns that this is an "experimental" feature. at least `\t` seems to work fine. but more advanced perl regex features may not.
- use printf to print a tab character for you:

  ```
  grep "$(printf '\t')" foo.txt
  ```
- use the literal tab character:

  ```
  grep "^V<tab>" foo.txt
  ```

  that is: type `grep "`, then press `ctrl+v`, then press `tab`, then type `" foo.txt`. pressing `ctrl+v` in the terminal causes the next key to be taken verbatim. that means the terminal will insert a tab character instead of triggering some function bound to the tab key.
- use the [ansi c quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) feature of bash:

  ```
  grep $'\t' foo.txt
  ```

  this does not work in all shells.
- use awk:

  ```
  awk '/\t/'
  ```
- use sed:

  ```
  sed -n '/\t/p'
  ```

See the [wikipedia article about regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for an overview of the defined character classes in POSIX and other systems.

Comment: basing on enzotib's answer let me add the following: `grep $'\t' foo.txt` (but I would usually write `fgrep` instead of `grep`)

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that BSD (including OSX) grep, lacks the -P option.

Comment: From the man page `This is highly experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.` Probably not a good idea to use `-P` in legacy systems. The `printf` choice is better

Answer (score 19):

It is not exactly the answer you would want to hear, but a possible use of escape sequences is provided by bash

```
command | grep $'\t'
```

(do not put it into double quotes!).

Comment: Indeed, I suggest that @enzotib edit the answer to be simply `grep $'\t'`.

Comment: It should be stressed that this is a feature of bash and will (silently!) do the wrong thing if executed by some other shell (such as dash, which is the default for shell scripts on Ubuntu and others)

Comment: @xjcl I never heard of `dash` being the default on Ubuntu - my Ubuntu always had `bash`. Can you back that statement up with any source, please?

Comment: @jena bash is the default for interactive sessions. But non-interactive scripts default to /bin/sh which is a link to dash. You can verify this with `ls -la /bin/sh`

Comment: @xjcl - interesting, I really never encountered it until now. Anyway, the question is tagged with `bash` so I think it's "stressed" enough.

Comment: @jena If you use it interactively or in a .bashrc file you will be fine, but if you use it in cron for example this will bite you (as cron defaults to `/bin/sh`, not bash)

Answer (score 3):

**`awk '/\t/'`** is my favorite workaround:

```
printf 'a\t\nb' | awk '/\t/'
```

Output: `a\t`.

Answer (score 2):

One can always resort to using ascii hex-code for tab:

```
$ echo "one"$'\t'"two" > input.txt                                 

$ grep -P "\x9" input.txt                                          
one two

$ grep $'\x9' input.txt                                            
one two
```